# Comment décomposer 'pour ce que de telles choses' ?

Tags: sens, syntaxe, moyen-français

[Source qui a actualisé l'orthographe](http://www.historia.fr/web/complement-mensuel/la-creation-de-letat-civil-02-12-2010-45041) : *L'ordonnance de Villers-Cotterêts*, le 25 août 1539

> Et pour **ce que de telles choses** sont souvent advenues sur l'[intelligence](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/intelligence) des mots latins contenus dans lesdits arrêts, nous voulons dorénavant que tous [...] soient prononcés, enregistrés et délivrés aux parties, en langage maternel françoys et non aultrement.

Je ne suis pas certain si la syntaxe grasse puisse être possible en français moderne (qui diffère du moyen français), mais je voudrais faire l'analyse grammaticale de toute façon.

Comment  désambiguîser le  **de** ? Veuillez expliquer vos étapes et votre mécanisme de la pensée.

1. Est-il une préposition ici? Dans ce cas, **ce que DE telles choses**
   ⟹  **ce que DÉCOULANT OU PROVENANT DE  telles choses**.
2. Ou est-il un article partitive ?  Dans ce cas, **ce que DE telles choses**
   ⟹  **ce que CERTAINS telles choses**.

PS: Je sais qu'ici, 'intelligence' détient le sens de son étymon latin: intelligibilité.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu as mal découpé la phrase : « *<s>ce que de</s> » ne constitue pas un groupe qui ait un sens. On a la locution conjonctive « pour ce que » (un groupe de mots qui a la fonction de conjonction de subordination), suivi du groupe nominal « de telles choses » qui est le sujet du verbe. Voici le début de la phrase avec des parenthèses autour des groupes de mots qui forment une unité syntaxique :

> Et (pour ce que) ((de (telles) choses) sont (souvent) (advenues) (sur l'intelligence (des mots (latins) (contenus dans lesdits arrêts)))), …

Le *de* dans « de telles choses » est un [article partitif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_partitif) banal (avec la forme *de* au pluriel parce qu'il est suivi d'un adjectif).

Quant à « pour ce que », c'est une forme ancienne de « parce que » qui a disparu en français moderne.

La phrase signifie donc « et parce qu'il s'est passé [des ambiguïtés, des incertitudes et des demandes d'interprétation] au sujet de la compréhension des mots latins contenus dans [les décisions de justice en latin], … »

Answer (score 2):

*Pour ce que* est devenu [*parce que*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parce_que) en français moderne et joue donc le rôle d'une conjonction de subordination. La proposition introduite (reportée ci-dessous) exprime une cause, un motif ou une raison.

> De telles choses sont souvent advenues sur l'intelligence des mots latins contenus dans lesdits arrêts.

Dans cette proposition, *de* est simplement l'article pluriel indéfini « des » (aussi appelé partitif pluriel) raccourci devant un adjectif. Il ne s'agit pas d'une préposition.